# Adobe native Air app works on windows7 but not on windowsXP?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flexbuilder

Well i have an adobe air app that captures screen and saves image on desktop. The App works fine on windows 7 but it just does not work on windowsXp..
The App use native windows exe that was built in C# using Visual Studio 2010.
Its video tutorial and code is given at

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/

The app just does not work on windows and gives no compile time or runtime time error and offcourse it does not save image on desktop.

Kindly help me on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is solved by installing updated .net framwork 4 and as i write in my question that it uses native windows exe that was built in C# using Visual Studio 2010 so Visual Studio 2010 uses .net framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

You may install flexbuilder on winXP and debug it there.

There is global exception handler in AIR, but it saves no stack trace (yet), so it gives only error code.

Comment: I am runnig same code on XP using FLex Builder 4 and same sdk. and it shows no error.